# Create a calendar database table like this

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I would like to create a calendar SQL table like this one but for some years.
(I'm using mysql 5.7.28)
Date is DD-MM-YYYY

[image: Text]

Is it possible?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Date functions and recursive fonctionalities are highly vendor dependent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know.. I'm using mysql

Comment: If date is dmy don't bother with an rdbms

Comment: @Strawberry Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select '2019-01-01 00:00:00' dt
    union all 
    select dt + interval 1 hour from cte where dt < '2020-01-01' - interval 1 hour
)
select
    row_number() over(order by dt) id,
    date(dt) day,
    time(dt) start_hour,
    time(dt + interval 1 hour) end_hour
from cte
```

The recursive cte generates a list of `datetime`s between the given boundaries (here, that's year 2019), with a 1 hour increment. Then, the outer query produces the expected result, by extracting the day and hour parts.

You can adjust the boudaries and the increment as per your exact requirements.

Side note: I would suggest to retain the full datetime in the calendar table as well; there are many situation where having a proper datetime value is more convenient than separated dates and times.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cb5eb4e9c2c006c298529295a65a381)** for the first day only:

```
id | day        | start_hour      | end_hour       
-: | :--------- | :-------------- | :--------------
 1 | 2019-01-01 | 00:00:00.000000 | 01:00:00.000000
 2 | 2019-01-01 | 01:00:00.000000 | 02:00:00.000000
 3 | 2019-01-01 | 02:00:00.000000 | 03:00:00.000000
 4 | 2019-01-01 | 03:00:00.000000 | 04:00:00.000000
 5 | 2019-01-01 | 04:00:00.000000 | 05:00:00.000000
 6 | 2019-01-01 | 05:00:00.000000 | 06:00:00.000000
 7 | 2019-01-01 | 06:00:00.000000 | 07:00:00.000000
 8 | 2019-01-01 | 07:00:00.000000 | 08:00:00.000000
 9 | 2019-01-01 | 08:00:00.000000 | 09:00:00.000000
10 | 2019-01-01 | 09:00:00.000000 | 10:00:00.000000
11 | 2019-01-01 | 10:00:00.000000 | 11:00:00.000000
12 | 2019-01-01 | 11:00:00.000000 | 12:00:00.000000
13 | 2019-01-01 | 12:00:00.000000 | 13:00:00.000000
14 | 2019-01-01 | 13:00:00.000000 | 14:00:00.000000
15 | 2019-01-01 | 14:00:00.000000 | 15:00:00.000000
16 | 2019-01-01 | 15:00:00.000000 | 16:00:00.000000
17 | 2019-01-01 | 16:00:00.000000 | 17:00:00.000000
18 | 2019-01-01 | 17:00:00.000000 | 18:00:00.000000
19 | 2019-01-01 | 18:00:00.000000 | 19:00:00.000000
20 | 2019-01-01 | 19:00:00.000000 | 20:00:00.000000
21 | 2019-01-01 | 20:00:00.000000 | 21:00:00.000000
22 | 2019-01-01 | 21:00:00.000000 | 22:00:00.000000
23 | 2019-01-01 | 22:00:00.000000 | 23:00:00.000000
24 | 2019-01-01 | 23:00:00.000000 | 00:00:00.000000
```

---

In earlier versions, you would typically create a large table of numbers by cross-joining subqueries, and use the number range to increment the initial date. `row_number()` can be emulated with a MySQL variable:

```
select
    @id:=@id + 1 id,
    date(dt) day,
    time(dt) start_hour,
    time(dt + interval 1 hour) end_hour,
    0 prenoted
from (
    select '2019-01-01' + interval d0.n + 10 * d1.n + 100 * d2.n + 1000 * d3.n hour dt
    from 
        (
            select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select  4
            union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
        ) d0
        cross join (
            select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select  4
            union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
        ) d1
        cross join (
            select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select  4
            union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
        ) d2
        cross join (
            select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select  4
            union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
        ) d3
    where '2019-01-01' + interval d0.n + 10 * d1.n + 100 * d2.n + 1000 * d3.n hour < '2020-01-01'
) t
cross join (select @id := 0 id) i
order by dt
```

The above query gives you a maximum span of 10 000 hours (wich represent a little more than 416 days); you can add another cross join and update the arithmetic to handle up to 100 000 hours (and so on).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5311dcada45e007f6332d9fe3187bb92)** for the first 24 hours.

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.7.28

Comment: @DavideMelis: ok, I updated my answer with a solution for MySQL < 8.0.

Comment: Does it miss the boolean prenotated field? And is it correct the "select 5 union all select 5" or it should be select 5 union all select 6"?

Comment: @DavideMelis: yes it should be `select 5 union all select 6`, I fixed that typo. From your sample result I could not tell what `prenoted` is supposed to be, so I left it apart...

Comment: could you add it please? prenoted has to be a boolean field initialized to false

Comment: @DavideMelis: that's an obvious, minor change to the query... done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203632/discussion-between-davide-melis-and-gmb).

Comment: @DavideMelis to create the table from the select statement, you would use [`CREATE TABLE table_name (SELECT ....)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) like so: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXCDMq5z3Q1Kz8rZexqgyb/0